# host port forward with qemu through libvirt in user-mode networking

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, forwarding, libvirt, qemu

I'm having trouble editing my libvirt's host-xml to make qemu forward TCP connections to the guest.  [This questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/720153/port-forwarding-with-libvirt) linked to [a blog post](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/running-qemu-with-port-redirection-through-libvirt/) which recommended adding `-redir` to the Qemu command line. But that stopped working as of recently.

> error: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor:
>   qemu-system-x86_64: -redir tcp:5564::3389: The -redir option is
>   deprecated. Please use '-netdev user,hostfwd=...' instead.

That, however, doesn't work out of the box, i.e. I get the open port on the host, but it doesn't go through to the client.

I edited my XML like this:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  .
  .
  .
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-net'/>
    <qemu:arg value='user,hostfwd=tcp::22222-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8000-:8000'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

My test was to then run `nc -l -p 8000` on the client and `telnet localhost 8000` on the host.  Telnet indicates an opened TCP connection but the client doesn't receive anything.

I guess it's because libvirt already included a `-net user,...` option and somehow my newly defined option isn't processed properly.  `ps aux | grep qemu` shows this:

> qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=myguestsname,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=~/.config/libvirt/qemu/lib/domain-28-myguestsname/master-key.aes -machine pc-i440fx-artful,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off -cpu Skylake-Client -m 1024 -realtime mlock=off -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid 713287321 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=~/.config/libvirt/qemu/lib/domain-28-myguestsname/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay -no-hpet -no-shutdown -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x7 -device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x5 -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x1 -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x2 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -drive file=~/.local/share/libvirt/images/myguestsname.img,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive file=Cloud-Init-ISO/master-init.iso,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -fsdev local,security_model=mapped,id=fsdev-fs0,path=~/guestfs -device virtio-9p-pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev-fs0,mount_tag=guestsfs,bus=pci.0,addr=0x9 -netdev user,id=hostnet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:aa:aa:0a,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0,bus=usb.0,port=1 -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on -device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::22222-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8000-:8000 -msg timestamp=on

We can see `-netdev user,id=hostnet0`. I tried to use the same name in my custom command line, but that fails:

> error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
>   qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev
>   pty,id=charserial0: char device redirected to /dev/pts/23 (label
>   charserial0)
>
> qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:aa:aa:0a,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3: Property 'virtio-net-device.netdev' can't take value 'hostnet0', it's
>   in use

For non user-mode networking setups, [several](https://serverfault.com/questions/710168/forward-port-on-guest-operating-system-with-libvirt) [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/170079/forwarding-ports-to-guests-in-libvirt-kvm) exist already. 
But I need to work with user-mode networking.

How would I properly forward ports using libvirt with qemu and user-mode networking?

The [documentation](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html) is not really helpful, here, because it does not say how to sort of override already existing device definitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the missing part from your configuration is described here: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking. You have to add another netdev with new address like so:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
.
.
.
 </devices>
 <qemu:commandline>
   <qemu:arg value='-netdev'/>
   <qemu:arg value='user,id=mynet.0,net=10.0.10.0/24,hostfwd=tcp::22222-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8000-:8000'/>
   <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
   <qemu:arg value='e1000,netdev=mynet.0'/>
 </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

Comment: Then libvirt doesn't see that the machine has a NIC which has the weird side effect that virt-manager doesn't show traffic. how easy is it to use a virtio NIC with this scheme?

Comment: how would I do that with a virtio nic?

Comment: The mihais' answer is correct. I just wanted to ref the libvirt issue on this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=679117 for further following up.