# How to ensure that the changes in domain XML spec in libvirt takes effect?

Tags: linux-networking, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I followed this [host port forward with qemu through libvirt in user-mode networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/890520/host-port-forward-with-qemu-through-libvirt-in-user-mode-networking) answer to accomplish a certain task but it was only after a reboot that the ports were actually accessible. I tried restarting the domain but it did not work. What should I do to ensure that the changes take effect without restarting the host?

Comment: Restart the host. - or use qemu interface to do onlin modifications, which will not persist.

Comment: @NiKiZe, that is something I'm trying to avoid. Are you sure there is no other way around it?